# C++ function returning 'inf' instead of double

Tags: c++, floating-point, double

I have the following simple code that computes the nth harmonic number. No matter what I try I keep getting an 'inf' value in the output. How is this possible, even if all my variables are doubles?

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

double harmonic(double n){
    double h = 0.0;
    while(n >= 0){
        h = h + (1.0/n);
        n = n-1.0;

    }
    return(h);
}
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    double n;
    cout << "enter an integer: ";
    cin >> n;
    cout << "The " << n << "th harmonic number is: ";
    cout << harmonic(n) << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `inf` is a value of type `double`, just like `1.0` is.

Comment: If you stepped through this in a debugger, it might become obvious what is happening (debugging is a critical programming skill).

Comment: @MarkRansom Silly, `inf` is a floating point value, but in `double` it is pronounced `infinf`.

Comment: Curious, why not use int for n? you're treating it as an integer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Think about this:

```
while(n >= 0){
    h = h + (1.0/n);
    n = n-1.0;

}
```

Say I passed in `n = 0.0`. The loop will execute, yet `n = 0` and hence you are performing a division by zero.

Answer (score 3):

`inf` is a special floating point value, arising, for example, from division over zero. The latter indeed happens in your program: when `n` reaches zero, your loop still continues and you try to divide `1.0` over zero.

Change your loop to `while (n>0)`.

Comment: `n` could still be greater than zero and `1/n` would still produce `inf` for sufficiently small `n`.

Comment: @sjdowling, good point, though I really do think OP intended `n` to be `int`, not `double`; otherwise it not clear at all what output are they expecting to obtain.